# Configure cache on GitLab runner - install dependencies by composer only once

Tags: php, caching, composer-php, gitlab

I have problem with gitlab cache config.

I use GitLab Community Edition 11.7.7, in docs we have: 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-php-dependencies

So, my config:

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
  - code-style
  - analysis

before_script:
  - composer global require hirak/prestissimo
  - composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts

php-cs-fixer:
  stage: code-style
  script:
    - vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --diff --verbose --config=.php_cs.dist src tests

php-cs-fixer2:
  stage: analysis
  script:
      - vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --diff --verbose --config=.php_cs.dist src tests
```

Unfortunately, composer re-installs all dependencies in every job.

I would like to install all dependencies through the composer only once, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration is similar to my own that run on self-hosting Gitlab at my company, I think it should works as well, So I have created an [sample repo](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci) that runs pipelines based on your configuration in order to reproduce your problem.

As you can see [here](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/pipelines), I was trying to make a working pipeline by complete the configuration, For example, wrong image, missing composer executable...something like that, The [final configuration](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) is not much diffrent to yours.

```
image: php:7.2-alpine

cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
  - code-style
  - analysis

before_script:
  - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
  - php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
  - php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  - export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
  - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
  - composer global require hirak/prestissimo
  - composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts

php-cs-fixer:
  stage: code-style
  script:
    - vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --diff --verbose --config=.php_cs.dist src tests || true
  allow_failure: true

php-cs-fixer2:
  stage: analysis
  script:
      - vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --diff --verbose --config=.php_cs.dist src tests
  allow_failure: true
```

The last job [#97744833](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/pipelines/97744833) have a clue to answer your problem.

Compare the last part of outputs from previous failed job https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/-/jobs/358118759#L191

```
187 Checked all files in 0.006 seconds, 10.000 MB memory used
191 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 8
```

to https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/-/jobs/358121571#L190

The cache is creating when build success.

```
190 Creating cache master...
191 vendor/: found 4860 matching files                 
192 Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/15472690/master 
193 Created cache
196 Job succeeded
```

So, after cache created, The job on the next stage should be ok for downloading cache archive.

https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/-/jobs/358121572#L20

```
18 Checking cache for master...
19 Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/15472690/master 
20 Successfully extracted cache
```

https://gitlab.com/Gasol/php-composer-cache-on-gitlab-ci/-/jobs/358121572#L46

And there are nothing to install when cache extracted. That's the result you want.

```
43 $ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts
44 Loading composer repositories with package information
45 Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
46 Nothing to install or update
47 Generating autoload files
```